# Egit does not allow me to add files to index

Tags: eclipse, egit

I have been able to add two files to the index, but when I add other files to the index nothing happens. The other files don't show up in the Team > Commit dialog either.

I noticed this started happening after I accidentally exited out of Eclipse while an EGit commit was in progress of these very same files. I checked and the commit never took place.

I have tried restarting eclipse and looking for .gitignore files.

Update:
Apparently commit is stored somewhere, I just have to push it.

Answer (score 0):

Just had to push it to upstream and it worked.